# Path-Mapped Azure Blob Storage keeps Azure App Service from Starting

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-path-mappings, I have mounted a blob storage container in my Azure App Service.

The Flask App was running fine, until I uploaded a large, 16GB file into the storage container. Now the app won't start. The problem seems to be that the docker container cannot be created in time. I get the following logs:

```
2020-06-16T08:17:46.912Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container xyz_0_8ece6717 for site xyz

2020-06-16T08:18:02.665Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container xyz_0_8ece6717. Elapsed time = 15.7514997 sec
2020-06-16T08:19:42  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
```

until the max wait time of 1800 seconds is reached. 
Sometimes I also get another error message:

```
2020-06-16T08:39:47.167Z ERROR - [BYOS] Azure storage volume abc for site xyz faulted.
```

When I change the path mapping to an empty storage container, it loads fine ( well it crashes, cause the files are missing. but that's to be expected...)

What can I do to 
a) fix this?
b) debug this further?

Or are storage containers not supposed to house large files?